# what mean $\overline{\text{span}(e_1,...,e_n)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

In functional analysis, what mean
$$\overline{\text{span}(e_1,...,e_n)} \ \ ?$$

is it the closure of $\text{span}(e_1,...,e_n)$ ?
How does it work ? Even if it's that, I don't understand how $\text{span}(e_1,...,e_n)$ can have a closure (because it's a vector space).

Comment: Every subset of a topological space has a closure.

Comment: Could you specify where it occures? Maybe there is some addition operation in ambient spaces.

Comment: A finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ is always isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$ for some $n$, these are topolological spaces and that topology can be transferred to $V$.  Then you check that the topology you get on $V$ doesn't depend on the choice of isomorphism and voila!  $V$ becomes a topological space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional analysis one of the main objects of study is the study of topological vector spaces. That is a vector space $V$ and a topology $\tau$ of $V$, such that the functions 
$$ V\times V \xrightarrow{+} V$$
and
$$ \mathbb{C} \xrightarrow{\cdot v} V$$
are continuous. 
One of the main examples of topological vector spaces are normed spaces, where the topology is induced by a norm $\|\cdot\|:V \rightarrow V$. A sub examples of this kind are Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces.

$\overline{span(e_1,\ldots,e_n)}$ just means the closure of $span(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ with respect to the topology of $V$.